# Too many unprocessed floats

Tags: floats, errors

I'm trying to a large number of figures. The code is

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{m2T4.pdf}
\caption{M2T, Problem Size 513}
\end{figure}
```

I'm not able to compile, I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.113 \includegraphics
[scale=0.5]{m2T4.pdf}
You've lost some text. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@float@Hx ...ltovf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox
\color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.113 \includegraphics
[scale=0.5]{m2T4.pdf}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\vbox
l.113 \includegraphics
[scale=0.5]{m2T4.pdf}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./m2T4.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1
.5>, but at most version <1.4> allowed
<m2T4.pdf, id=1121, 538.28104pt x 212.1526pt>
File: m2T4.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use m2T4.pdf>
```

Comment: you may want to take a look at the theory behind it at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the command `\clearpage`. This prints all floats that are not yet placed and starts a new page.

Comment: Hi, where is supposed I must put the `\clearpage` command.

Comment: where do you put `\clearpage` ?

Comment: @cmo, somewhere in your document where it would make sense to start a new page (it's really up to you).

Answer (score 44):

Try the [`morefloats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) package. From the README:

> LaTeX can, by default, only cope with 18 outstanding floats; any more, and you get the error "too many unprocessed floats". This package releases the limit; TeX itself imposes limits (which are interdependent of the help offered by e-TeX).
>   However, if your floats can’t be placed anywhere, extending the number of floats merely delays the arrival of the inevitable error message.

Comment: Can there be any adverse consequence from using this package?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw the package has been essentially obsolete since 2015, latex has built in features now.

Answer (score 29):

For LaTeX releases from 2015/01/01 onwards you can allocate more (several thousand more)
floats than the standard 18, using a command such as

```
\extrafloats{100}
```

in the preamble. As this mechanism uses the etex extended box registers it can allocate many more float boxes than the `morefloats` package mechanism (which uses `\newinsert` and is thus restricted to the classic TeX registers 0-255).

If for some reason you are using a LaTeX format built on tex rather than etex, `\extrafloats` is still defined, but falls back to using `\newinsert` so fewer float boxes are available.

**Edit**, from the 2015/10/01 LaTeX release the default number of floats is increased from 18 to 52, and these reserved floats may also be used by `\newinsert` once the classic TeX registers run out.

Comment: After using `\extrafloats{100}` I got a message `! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.`

Comment: @Viesturs then some document that you have not shown has an error. If you need help with that then ask a question with a small example that shows the error.

Comment: Adding ````\extrafloats{200}````, then got the message ````! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles````, then I added ````\maxdeadcycles=500````, it worked for me. I'm using ````tufte-handout```` Bible text annotations, I use too many ````\footnote```` which causes the problems. It seems ````morefloats```` didn't work for my situation. It might be better than use ````\clearpage```` from time to time. But I need a programming solution, that I cannot afford to add such manually.

Comment: @YuShen (late response, sorry). `\footnote` are not floats so are not related to this message.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the `float` package and then the `[H]` option for your figure.

```
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{slike/visina8}
\caption{Write some caption here}\label{visina8}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you think of any potentially serious downsides to the method you've proposed? If so, you should probably mention them so that readers who come across your posting are fully aware of the pros and cons of the solution you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which can also help you control where your figures end up in relation to your text, is to us a `\FloatBarrier`. As the name suggests, it prevents floats from crossing the barrier such that all of your figures above the barrier will be above that point in the document and all of the figures below will be below.

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins} %Float Barriers
\FloatBarrier
```