# line spacing document class article

Tags: floats, line-spacing, article, setspace

I want to have more space between the lines in my document which uses documentclass `article`. But if I use something like [this blog](http://texblog.org/2011/09/30/quick-note-on-line-spacing/) says, it causes following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
   Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.539 \begin{figure}[h]
                   
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
\latex@xfloat ...vf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox 
                                              \color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.539 \begin{figure}[h]
                   
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \vbox 
l.539 \begin{figure}[h]
                   
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
...
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT**: using XeLaTeX

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't know how to, because the document works fine without `\usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}` in the header. The MWE works fine without AND with the lines in the header. I think theres an individual problem by the figures. But why is there something changing by line stretching?

Comment: can't simulate situation, sorry :( Maybe it help: the pdf is created anyway, but the figures are on the top of some text, or on the border so you only could see the half of it. And sometimes (in an itemize) the text overlaps a page... sorry for the poor informations :(

Comment: check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46512)

Comment: That blog post suggests several things; and how are you getting an error and yet the 'MWE works fine without AND with the lines in the header'?  Anyway, the line `! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.` might very well be accurate; to quote from *The LaTeX Companion*: 'LaTeX can defer up to 18 floats, then you will receive this error message.  Using the package `morefloats` will increase this limit to 36 but if there is a float that cannot be placed for some reason this change will merely delay receiving the above error.'  Potential solution: follow @henrique's link.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `\setspace` is not really related to the error shown other than the fact that it affects the vertical space so like any such change can affect the page breaking which in turn affects float placement.

You have used

\begin{figure}[h]

using [h]`means that LaTeX is prevented from putting the float in all the places that it normally puts the floats, top, bottom and page floats are all disallowed. This would make this error almost inevitable so LaTeX typically issues a warning and converts`[h]`to`[ht]` to give itself a chance, but without allowing page floats it is still very difficult to position the floats so they all get held up until you run out of allocated float registers.

use `[htp]` if you must use the optional argument at all.