# isov2 document class and symbols list

Tags: formatting, lists

I am currently using the **isov2** document class.  I would like to create a list of symbols.  I currently have the following output (style)

[image: Current Symbols List Formatting]

using the code:

```
\begin{symbols}
\symboldef{ACSE}{association control service element}
\end{symbols}
```

However, I'd like instead for the abbreviation and "definition" to be on one line, no extra line break in between the lines and *without* an indent similar to the image below:

[image: Ideal Symbols List Formatting]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple redefinition of the `symbols` environment (a list) will do:

```
\documentclass{isov2}

\renewenvironment{symbols}{\list{}%
    {\itemsep 0pt \parsep 0pt \itemindent 0em \leftmargin 5em
     \labelsep 1em \labelwidth 4em
     \let\makelabel\symbollabel}}%
    {\endlist}

\begin{document}

Some text here
\begin{symbols}
\symboldef{ACSE}{association control service element}
\symboldef{ADSE}{association domination service element}
\end{symbols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, here's the original definition from `isov2.cls`:

```
\newenvironment{symbols}{\list{}%
    {\itemindent 0em \leftmargin 8em
     \labelsep 1em \labelwidth 5em
     \let\makelabel\symbollabel}}%
    {\endlist}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have the PDF of the iso class, "LaTeX for ISO standards" however, I'm still fairly new to LaTeX and I haven't found a resource for redefining environments or learning more of the "programmer" part of LaTeX.

Comment: @KhoriWood You're welcome! I was wondering if you are still interested in an answer to this other question of yours: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192324/3954 (I provided a way to suppress the word "Page", but there's still some issue unsolved).

Comment: Thank you I definitely still needed that answer and wasn't sure how to make the post noticeable that I added information.  Thank you again for another great resolution.