# Too Many Unprocessed Floats Error

Tags: floats, errors

I have around 20 images to scan a copy of my work book. I want to make a PDF of them. But during the insertion of these files, I am getting the error "Too many unprocessed floats".

For some number of image files I am able to compile. But after some I am getting the error. How can I remove this error?

Comment: See if the suggestions in [Too many unprocessed floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46512)

Comment: Floats are supposed to float, i.e. LaTeX puts them where they fit best. If you want to put 20 scanned images from a workbook in a PDF, I think you want them in a certain order, so you do not need floats. Have a look at `pdfpages` and `\includepdf`. Or, if the scans are in JPEG format, `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I am not using float anywhere. These occurs in the error message

Comment: \begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=18cm]{IMG-1}\hfill
\end{figure}

Comment: An environment `figure` is a float.  Do not use it, if you do not need floats ...