# More floats with memoir

Tags: floats, memoir, marginpar

I'm writing a thesis with *memoir*. The numerous footnotes are rendered as sidenotes (marginpars) using memoir's `\footnotesinmargin` (memman.pdf p245). This, with the addition of the *marginfix* package, produces very satisfactory results.

However, even with judicious use of `\setFloatBlock{section}` and `\usepackage{morefloats}` (from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46512/too-many-unprocessed-floats)), the total number of floats sometimes exceeds 36, causing "Too many unprocessed floats" or (with morefloats) "Too many floats requested" errors. `\usepackage[morefloats=n]{morefloats}` also throws the latter error.

The output in fact looks OK, but I would like to fix this error. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241006/78941) mentions that with LaTeX from 01.01.2015, there is the facility to simply request `\extrafloats`. I have upgraded to TexLive 2015, but this doesn't seem to work if the document's class is memoir. With an minimal working example like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\extrafloats{100}
\title{Memoir with extrafloats}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I get a fatal error like:

```
(c:/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mempatch.sty))
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.2 \extrafloats{100}
```

Is there any easy solution here to get more than 36 floats? I am reluctant to unpick everything when it is otherwise working very well and the answer seems close.

Comment: I don't get an error with the above code with latest miktex.

Comment: This compiles with the latest updates for TeX Live 2015. I know memoir was updated over the summer and there was a latex release earlier in the month. I think installing the latest updates will get you back on track.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by a package update and therefore cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments, which led me to the solution: update to the latest version of *memoir*, which doesn't have this error.

For reference, version **3.7c (37021)**, as bundled with TexLive 2015, exhibited this problem, which is resolved with version **3.7e (37089)**.