# too many unprocessed floats, Undefined control sequence, missing number treated as zero

Tags: floats

Getting below type of error while trying to set eighteenth figure.

too many unprocessed floats, Undefined control sequence, missing number treated as zero

Comment: Hi, welcome. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46512/too-many-unprocessed-floats helps.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You presumably have an old latex (older than 2015) so while you could use `\clearpage` you might also want to update your tex system.